# Value getting toasted but not getting in textview?

Tags: android, eclipse, sockets, client, server

I am developing the android application in which sever sends the command to client and client side works on command and sends the result.

I am using handler in client side on every 15  sec to write the data on server side.

My problem is i am getting the output from client side and toasted correctly but the value is assigning to Textview first time which comes from client when the second time the value comes its getting toasted correctly but not assigning to Textview

Here my code Goes

Server Side

```
public class ServerSocketNew extends ActionBarActivity {
static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
 LinearLayout chatpanel, sendpanel;
 TextView infoIp, infoPort, chatMsg,contact,contact1;
 Button b1,b2,back,Files;
 EditText e1,e2;
    private File root;
    private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
 String msgLog = "";
 String prev="";
 String Message="Hies";
 String Flags="Trues";
 List<ChatClient> userList;
    int count=0;
 ServerSocket serverSocket;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_socket_new);
  infoIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
  infoPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoport);
  chatMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatmsg);
  b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
  b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Contacts);
  e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.say);
  e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Something);
  contact=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact);
  contact1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact1);
  infoIp.setText(getIpAddress());
     chatpanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chatpanel);
     sendpanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sendpanel);
     back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
     Files=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Files);
  OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Message=e1.getText().toString();
        Flags="Trues";
        count=0;

    }
};
  OnClickListener Listnerfiles=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Message="";
        Message="Files";
        Flags="Trues";
        sendpanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         chatpanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        count=0;
    }
};
  OnClickListener listener1=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Flags="Trues";
            Message="CONTACTS";
            sendpanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             chatpanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                count=0;
        }
    };
b1.setOnClickListener(listener);
b2.setOnClickListener(listener1);
Files.setOnClickListener(Listnerfiles);
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        e1.setText("");
        Message="CONTACTS";

        Flags="Trues";
        count=0;
    }
});
  userList = new ArrayList<ChatClient>();
  ChatServerThread chatServerThread = new ChatServerThread();
  chatServerThread.start();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();

  if (serverSocket != null) {
   try {
    serverSocket.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
 private class ChatServerThread extends Thread {

  @Override
  public void run() {
   Socket socket = null;

   try 
   {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
    ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      infoPort.setText("I'm waiting here: "
        + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
     }
    });

    while (true) {

     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
     userList.add(client);

     ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(client, socket);
     connectThread.start();

    }

   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
    if (socket != null) {
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }

  }

 }

 private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

  Socket socket;
  ChatClient connectClient;
  String msgToSend = "";

  ConnectThread(ChatClient client, Socket socket){
   connectClient = client;
   this.socket= socket;
   client.socket = socket;
   client.chatThread = this;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

   try {
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    String n = dataInputStream.readUTF();

    connectClient.name = n;

    msgLog += connectClient.name + " connected@" + 
      connectClient.socket.getInetAddress() + 
      ":" + connectClient.socket.getPort() + "\n";
    ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
         infoIp.setText(msgLog);
     }
    });

    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Welcome " + n + "\n");
    dataOutputStream.flush();

    broadcastMsg(n + " join our chat.\n");

    while (true) {
     if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
      String newMsg = dataInputStream.readUTF();

      msgLog="";
      msgLog =  newMsg;
      ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
          // infoIp.setText(msgLog);
          // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prev="+prev, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "messagelog="+msgLog, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Number",msgLog);
          e2.setText(msgLog+"#"+msgLog);
           if(count<5)
         {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "messagelog="+msgLog, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

              contact.setText(msgLog);

         }
           count=count+1;

       }
      });

      broadcastMsg(n + ": " + newMsg);
     }

     if(!msgToSend.equals("")){
      dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msgToSend);
      dataOutputStream.flush();
      msgToSend = "";
     }

    }

   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    userList.remove(connectClient);
    ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(ServerSocketNew.this, 
       connectClient.name + " removed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      msgLog += "-- " + connectClient.name + " leaved\n";
      ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           infoIp.setText(msgLog);
       }
      });

      broadcastMsg("-- " + connectClient.name + " leaved\n");
     }
    });
   }

  }

  private void sendMsg(String msg){
   msgToSend = msg;
  }

 }

 private void broadcastMsg(String msg){
  for(int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++){
   userList.get(i).chatThread.sendMsg(Message);
   msgLog =  Message+"\n";
  }

  ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       infoIp.setText(msgLog);
   }
  });
 }
```

My client side Code

```
 public class CLIENTNEW123 extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
     DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
       DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

     LinearLayout loginPanel chatPanel;TextView chatMsg;static String fourth;


     Button buttonSend;


     String msgLog = "";
    String msgLog1="";
     String ret = null;
     String nameno="";
        String ret1 = null;
        Context context=this;
        String name="";
         String flags="false";

     ChatClientThread chatClientThread = null;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_clientnew123);
      final Handler handler = new Handler();

      loginPanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginpanel);
      chatPanel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chatpanel);

      chatMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatmsg);



       msgLog = "";
       chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
       loginPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       chatPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


       chatClientThread = new ChatClientThread(
         "aaa","192.168.43.1", SocketServerPORT);
       chatClientThread.start();


             Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

                    @Override 
                    public void run() { 
                        try{

                            chatClientThread.sendMsg("Namasted"+ "\n");
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 15*1000);
                            Log.e("In Handler", "In Handler");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                        finally{
                            //also call the same runnable 
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 15*1000); 
                        }
                    } 
                }; 
                handler.postDelayed(runable, 15*1000); 
     }
         private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {

      String name;
      String dstAddress;
      int dstPort;

      String msgToSend = "";
      boolean goOut = false;

        private File root;
        private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
        private LinearLayout view;
        String Filenames="";

         File[] fileArray;
      ChatClientThread(String name, String fourth, int port) {
       this.name = name;
       dstAddress = fourth;
       dstPort =8080;

      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
       Socket socket = null;


       try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
          socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(name);
        dataOutputStream.flush();

        while (!goOut) {
         if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
          msgLog1 = dataInputStream.readUTF();
         // msgLog += msgLog1;
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msgLog,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

          CLIENTNEW123.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
            chatMsg.setText(msgLog1);
           // name=msgLog;
                //abcd aa=new abcd();
            //aa.add(name);


           }
          });
          //sendMsg("name " + "\n");
         }


         if(!msgToSend.equals("")){
             if(msgLog1.equals("FilesNew"))
             {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.txt");
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    int bytesRead = is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    bos.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                    bos.close();
                    socket.close();
             }
             if(msgLog1.equals("Files"))
             {
                 flags="Files";
                 root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath());
                    fileList=getfile(root);

                    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
                        Filenames+=fileList.get(i).getName()+"#"+"\n";
                        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());
                        if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {

                        }
                                            }
                     dataOutputStream.writeUTF(Filenames+"\n");
                      dataOutputStream.flush();
             }



             else  if(msgLog1.equals("CONTACTS"))
             {
                 flags="true";
                 dataOutputStream.writeUTF("\n");
                  dataOutputStream.flush();
             }
             else if(flags=="true")
             {
                 String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'"+msgLog1+"%'";
                    String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

                    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, selection, null, null);
                    int indexName = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    int indexNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                    // Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                while(c.moveToNext()) {
                        ret = c.getString(indexName);
                        ret1 = c.getString(indexNumber);
                        nameno=nameno+" "+ret+" "+ret1;

                    }

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    ret = c.getString(0);
                    ret1 = c.getString(0);

                }

                    c.close();
                      dataOutputStream.writeUTF(nameno+"\n");
                      dataOutputStream.flush();
             }
             else
             {
                  dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Messgae lo"+msgLog1);
                  dataOutputStream.flush(); 
             }

          msgToSend = "";
         }
        }

       } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        final String eString = e.toString();
        CLIENTNEW123.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          Toast.makeText( CLIENTNEW123.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

        });
       }
      catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        final String eString = e.toString();
         CLIENTNEW123.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          Toast.makeText( CLIENTNEW123.this, eString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

        });
       } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
         try {
          socket.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
         try {
          dataOutputStream.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null) {
         try {
          dataInputStream.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }

         CLIENTNEW123.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          loginPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          chatPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }

        });
       }

      }
        public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
            File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
            if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                        fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                        getfile(listFile[i]);

                    } else {
                        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                                || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                                || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                                || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".pdf"))

                        {
                            fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return fileList;
        }

      private void sendMsg(String msg){
       msgToSend = msg;
      }

      private void disconnect(){
       goOut = true;
      }
     }

}
```

I toasted my string in run method of connectthread class 
like

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "messagelog="+msgLog, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And after that i am assigning the value to the textview

I am getting the correct value in toast.

i am getting the problem at server side near

```
 if(count<5)
         {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "messagelog="+msgLog, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

              contact.setText(msgLog);

         }
```

this code 
 In 'contact' textview i am setting the value
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to make another log or toast before `chatMsg.setText(msgLog1);`? And, what's the difference between `msgLog` AMD `msgLog1`?

Comment: chatMsg.setText(msgLog1) is on client side but i am getting the problem at server side the i recieve the value at server side and toast it

Comment: i am setting the value at server side in contact.setText(msgLog);

Comment: when you show toast for msgLog1 does is appear right on client side ?

Comment: ya it appears correctly and returning the correct value too.

Comment: try this  chatMsg.setText(" "+msgLog1);

Comment: but its the problem in  server side of contact.setText(msgLog); here

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using msgLog in UIThread,
thus its value replace when this thread repeat run method.
try to append new value on msgLog not just replace it

```
msgLog="";
while (true) {
 if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
  String newMsg = dataInputStream.readUTF();


  msgLog +=  newMsg;
  ServerSocketNew.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      // infoIp.setText(msgLog);
      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prev="+prev, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "messagelog="+msgLog, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("Number",msgLog);
      e2.setText(msgLog+"#"+msgLog);
       if(count<5)
     {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "messagelog="+msgLog, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        // Flags="False";
         // contact.setText("");
         // contact1.setText("");
          //contact1.setText(msgLog2);
          contact.setText(msgLog);

     }
       count=count+1;

   }
  });

  broadcastMsg(n + ": " + newMsg);
 }
```

Comment: but when i append the value i get the value with the previous values and i do not need the previous values and the part is the values are toasted but not assigned